# Objects: How to return the name of a property with the highest value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a function that accepts an array of objects called 'mountains'. They contain the name and elevation properties. The goal is to return the name of the mountain that has the highest elevation. Here is my code so far: Note: This code throws a Type Error unfortunately.

```
    function tallest(mountains) { 

   mountains = [
    {name: 'Mount Everest', elevation: 29029},
    {name: 'Mount Kilimanjaro', elevation: 19341 },
    {name: 'Mount Diablo', elevation: 3848 }
    ];

   var highestElevation = mountains.map(function(mountain) {
     return {
       name: mountain.name,
       highestMountain: Math.max.apply(Math, mountain.elevation)};
   });

      var tallestMountain = mountains.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.highestElevation - a.highestElevation;
      })[0];
}

console.log(tallest());
```

What is a valid solution to return the name of the mountain with the highest elevation?

Comment: _"What is a great way..."_ - For this you would have to define _great"_ first.

Comment: Just sort `mountains`, there's no need for `var highestElevation = ...` (which right now only throws a `TypeError`)

Comment: What I mean by "great" is "What is a valid solution to my problem?"

Comment: Then please write so in your question, and make it a [mcve] including all errors you get (like the already mentioned `TypeError` from `Math.max.apply(...)`)

Comment: Yes I knew about the type error which I should have included. I do have a lot more to learn about asking questions here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce iterates over all the mountains.  Checks if current elevation is higher than the maximum seen.
You don't really need to sort, since you're only after the maximum.

```js
function tallest(mountains) {

  mountains = [{
      name: 'Mount Everest',
      elevation: 29029
    },
    {
      name: 'Mount Kilimanjaro',
      elevation: 19341
    },
    {
      name: 'Mount Diablo',
      elevation: 3848
    }
  ];

  var tallest = mountains.reduce(function(max,mountain) {
    return mountain.elevation > max.elevation ? mountain : max
  });
  
  return tallest.name;
}

console.log(tallest());
```

Also note that you asked to return the name of the mountain.

Comment: Maybe you want to set initial value for reduce, if not `max.elevation` will throw exception

Comment: reduce uses the first element as the accumulator, so it shouldn't be a problem.  it'll only throw if mountains is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let   mountains = [{
      name: 'Mount Everest',
      elevation: 29029
    },
    {
      name: 'Mount Kilimanjaro',
      elevation: 19341
    },
    {
      name: 'Mount Diablo',
      elevation: 3848
    }
  ];

let name = mountains.reduce((acc,ele)=>{
 return acc.elevation<ele.elevation ? ele.elevation : acc;
},mountains[0])['name'];
console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most optimized one, with one single iteration:

```js
const mountains = [
    {name: 'Mount Everest', elevation: 29029},
    {name: 'Mount Kilimanjaro', elevation: 19341 },
    {name: 'Mount Diablo', elevation: 3848 }
];

const getTallest = () => {
    let tallest = mountains[0];

    mountains.forEach((mountain) => {
        if (mountain.elevation > tallest.elevation) {
            tallest = mountain;
        }
    });
    return tallest;
};

getTallest(mountains);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort()`

```js
function tallest(mountains) {
  var mountains = [
    {name: 'Mount Everest', elevation: 29029},
    {name: 'Mount Kilimanjaro', elevation: 19341 },
    {name: 'Mount Diablo', elevation: 3848 }
  ];

  mountains.sort((a, b) => a.elevation - b.elevation);  
  
  return mountains.pop();
}

console.log(tallest());
```